# How do I enter text from whatever point the cursor is in IE?

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen similar questions, but none seem to quite apply.

My script opens an IE window, presses a button to open a new frame, and tabs me down to put my cursor in a textbox, into which I want to put the contents of a cell from the current worksheet. (I still need to add code to keep IE in the foreground in case I get an Outlook notification or something..but haven't gotten around to it yet).

But from here, I can't think of how to do the simple command to enter text from where my cursor is in the IE window. It seems to be performing an operation on the last line, but it jumps out to another window or something.

I get an application-defined or object-defined error under this configuration, and a 438 Application Doesn't support this kind of operation/function if I use application.Seltext in place of application.text. Any thoughts?

```
Sub FillInternetForm()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "[website]"

While IE.busy
DoEvents
Wend


IE.Document.All("[Button on the website]").Click

For i = 1 To 400000000
    i = i + 1
Next i

Application.SendKeys "{TAB 3}", True

For i = 1 To 400000000
    i = i + 1
Next i

'this is the line where I'm stuck... 

Application.SelText = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use `SendKeys` for this?  This is really not the way to do this though - when automating IE it's much better to interact directly with the loaded document than to use SendKeys to navigate on the page.  Plenty of examples if you search here on SO.

Comment: Bucking for that coveted gold [sendkeys] badge @TimWilliams ?

Comment: Work with `getElementById` can you show the website?

Comment: @Jeeped - gold you say?  Not a fan of sendkeys - it has never worked reliably for me. OP does seem to like it though.

Comment: Folks, not to tilt my hand, but I am not the top programmer in the world. Can you please tell me how I could insert the getElementById into this program? That's why I'm using sendkeys, I can't find a working ID for the textbox so I can just .click it...

Comment: It's difficult to make any suggestions without the source HTML for the elements you want to work with.

Comment: SendKeys ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value worked perfectly. Thank you TimWilliams

Comment: I think SendKeys works well only when your working with in the same Application, Sending keystrokes to the active application little its just not so good idea ....

Comment: Tim, the html is behind a password unfortunately. I can interact with the main window, but when I try to interact with the frame that pops up after the button press using something other than send keys, I get an object error, maybe as if it's trying to apply it to the main window again. Not sure what's up. It's a custom built site and I'm hoping to get the builder's APIs tomorrow.

Comment: The sendkeys are actually filling the bill though for now. Only issue I'm stuck on now is trying to use them to hit the "Next" page button. If I could do that I could get through the whole thing that way. Anyone know why it wouldn't accept a sendkeys enter command there?